# Separating List by day created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm creating a site with rails and bootstrap where I have a list group populated with posts. I want to be able to have seperate list groups for each seperate day.

For example at the moment I have:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">User has... <%= post.title%> </h2 class="pull-r"> <span class="pull-right"><%=link_to 'View', post%></span></li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
```

Which give me:

[image]

However I want it to look like:

[image]

(though obviously with different posts for each day)

but I'm having trouble, any help would be great.

Comment: Your sample code only shows a loop for generating the items in your list group.  What have you attempted for looping through and creating a list group for each date?

Comment: I'm very new to rails so I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the records by date

```
# change the .all with your condition
@posts = Post.all.group_by(&:created_at)
```

Group by will return you a hash where date will be key and values will be array of records with created at for the date

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <% @posts.each do |date, posts| %>
    <li>
      <h3><%= date.to_date.to_s %></h3>
      <ul>
        <% posts.each do |post| %>
          <li class="list-group-item">
           User has... <%= post.title%> </h2 class="pull-r"> 
           <span class="pull-right"><%=link_to 'View', post%></span>    
          </li>
        <%end%>
     </ul>
    </li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however if i do this I get an error undefined method `title' for #<Array:0x007f264f2a1c38>

Comment: It's working now however its adding a date for each post rather than grouping the posts by day